# SQL query to return all students with GPA's < 3

Tags: sql

Heres the query I have so far:

```
SELECT s.student_num, s.student_name, AVG(CAST(e.grade as float)) as GPA
FROM students s, enrolls e
WHERE s.student_num=e.student_num
AND GPA < 3
GROUP BY s.student_name, s.student_num, GPA;
```

This outputs nothing. But, when I remove the `AND GPA < 3` condition, it return all students and all GPAs. How can I get this to return just the students with GPA's < 3?

Comment: tag your database also provide sample data

Answer (score 2):

- you shouldn't and you can't add aggregate function into your groups, after all you are grouping data to calculate that
- also always use explicit join.
- to filter result of a group by , you need to use `having`

```
SELECT s.student_num, s.student_name, AVG(CAST(e.grade as float)) as GPA
FROM students s
join enrolls e
on s.student_num=e.student_num
GROUP BY s.student_name, s.student_num
having GPA < 3;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although, this also makes it return nothing, as did my original attempt.

Comment: @PmacSweezY its because  you don't have any student with average grade less than 3

Comment: Checked that, and there definitely exists average gpa's of less than 3. There are 5 of them, in fact.

Comment: @PmacSweezY that can't be true , please provide sample data